# Django: retrieve all unseen posts for a user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django data model like this:

```
class Post(django.db.models.Model):
    text = django.db.models.CharField()

class Seen(django.db.models.Model):
    post = django.db.models.ForeignKey(Post)
    user = django.db.models.ForeignKey(django.contrib.auth.models.User)
```

Where I'm trying to keep track of posts, and which users have seen which posts.  How can I retrieve all posts which a given user has not seen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using exclude:

```
unseen_posts = Post.objects.exclude(seen__user=user)
```

Where `user` is a `django.contrib.auth.models.User` object, possibly `request.user`, if you are using middleware.

The `seen__user` string traverses backwards along the `forignKey` between `Post` and `Seen`, and then forwards along the `foreignKey` between `Seen` and `User`.

Comment: Why the Q object? Can't you do this by just using exclude instead of filter?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
seen = Seen.objects.select_related('post').filter(user=request.user)
if post not in [x.post for x in seen]:
    #do what you need
```

Note that ['select_related'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) is just a perfomance booster here.

Comment: Won't that just return posts which other users have seen, or nothing at all?

Comment: Don't believe `select_related` is needed, as you aren't accessing any properties of `Post`.  Also to get all posts, you can just perform an exclude on the list. `Post.objects.exclude(pk__in=[x.post for x in seen])`